# Two repositories (1 svn and 1 git) on same folder?

Tags: git, svn

We are working on a project for a client that has a git repository and we need to commit changes at the end of the week. In the same time, we also keep a local svn repository where we commit daily to keep track of changes. Would there be a problem to keep the .svn and .git in the same project folder? I'm thinking if I put the .svn in the gitingore and also tell svn to ignore the .git, I should be able to use the same project to commit daily on our local svn and also weekly on the git.

Has anyone tried this or does anyone see a problem with this approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to do that. There are tools that make it easier: [git-svn](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html)

Answer (score 3):

Please, for the sake of humanity just use git for this :).

Why don’t you just commit to git? You can set up you own central git repo and do your daily week work with that. At the end of the week you just do `git push client mybranch`. Or if you don’t like your client seeing your internal history, do:

```
git checkout clientbranch
git merge --squash our-internal-branch
git commit -m "all of this weeks work"
git push client clientbranch
```

Comment: I cannot yet convince my company to move all projects local repositories from svn to git :). However your answer is very helpful and I will try to use it as an argument in future discussions with them.

Comment: Then leave the other ones in svn, but don’t do crazy svn-git mixes. While I *am* a git fanboy, this is not about that: If the client requires you to use git anyways and with git being (I guess :) perfectly able to fulfill you requirements, you should just stick to it. Especially since your requirements is what git (being distributed) really shines at.

Comment: Wordpress plugins official repository still runs on svn, and many people might also like to manage their plugin on github, so that's one use case where you're stuck needing to use both.

Comment: Sometimes this option is required. There are legacy installations that can't be easily converted for a variety of reasons.